# How to SELECT row with MAX() data of column?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, sql-order-by

i have some table of database :

```
Transaction                    detail_transaction              product
2 (id_sale)                     1 (id_detail)                   3 (id_product)
Yes (status_paidOff)            2 (id_sale)                     fish rolls (product_name)
2020-05-28(transaction_date)    3 (id_product)
Product (sale_type)             7 (total_sale)
```

So the output are like:

### `Product Name`    `Total Sale`

```
Fish rolls               7
```

i want to select a row in `detail_transaction` that has a **MAX** `total_sale`, with conditions :

- it has paid-off = Yes
- the transaction on month 5th (you can use `MONTH(transaction_date)=5`)
- sale type is `Product`

Can anyone help me with these?

Comment: which SQL engine are you using? could you please tag? Also provide test data and expected output in tabular form.

Comment: i've provided the test data above, but just 1 data, you can added more by seeing the data above. for expected output, i've also put it there, please read more correctly

Comment: This is ambiguous. Do you want (A) Of all paid off June/Product transactions those with the maximum total sale? Or (B) Of all maximum sale transactions those that are paid off June/Product transactions?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner (B) it is

Comment: The accepted answer is (A), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the top row from `detail_transaction` that satisfies the condition, you can join `detail_transaction` to `transaction`, filter with a `where` clause, then `order by` and `limit`:

```
seslect dt.*
from detail_transaction dt
inner join transaction t on t.id_sale = dt.id_sale
where 
    t.status_paidoff = 'yes' 
    and month(t.transaction_date) = 5
    and t.sale_type = 'Product'
order by dt.total_sale desc
limit 1
```

Comment: it works correctly, can you tell me how it works because i don't see you are using MAX(total_sale), so i dont know how it works, it goes right, MAX has selected

Comment: @Ellie: this works by sorting the resultset by descending `total_sale` (`order by dt.total_sale desc`), and then keeping the top row only (`limit 1`).

Comment: @Ellie: All transactions that match the conditions get ordered descending by their totals. Then only the first row gets shown. So if there are three products with totals 10, 7, and 2, the one with total = 10 is kept. If there are three products with totals 10, 10, and 2, then one of the two products with total = 10 is picked. It is hence a solution that doesn't consider ties which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @GMB Genius, Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for the explanations, it's helpfull